# Processing curl output in perl

Tags: regex, perl, curl

I'm processing the output from `curl -s`.
Specifically from this page:  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/971058/how-do-i-reset-windows-update-components

Before I state my goal, I'll mention I'm only interested in answers that extract the required data from the curl output of this page.  (I'm aware that the actions suggested on this page are already available as text, powershell scripts, etc.)

The end goal is to get a list of the dlls.  It *was* to do it quickly without any fuss (so a one-liner), but it's now become a learning experience for me.  The basic regex is `/regsvr32.exe (.*?\.dll)/`.

The curl output I'm interested in looks like this (note the lack of line breaks):

`<li>regsvr32.exe a.dll</li><li>regsvr32.exe b.dll</li>`etc

So I tried perl like the following:
`perl -F"li" -lane 'print $1 if /regsvr32.exe (.*?\.dll)/g'`

(The logic being I could split sloppily on any occurrence of "li" and should still get reasonable results I could fine-tune later)

I could not get `-F` to work *at all*.  I tried single characters, I tried regexes like /PATTERN/, I tried omitting various other flags (particularly `-l`), I wrote a one-liner to show the splits.  I could not make a split occur.

Then I checked the curl man page to see if it had any output sanitizers that might help.  It's a looong man page, but I didn't see anything.

Then it occurred to me that it'd be nice if the perl I wrote worked regardless if the same regex matched multiple times on the same line.  But I couldn't find anything that would be reasonable for a one-liner.

The sanest thing I could find to produce the desired output as a one-liner was this:

```
curl -vs \
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/971058/how-do-i-reset-windows-update-components 2>&1 | \
perl -pe 's|</li>|\n|g' | \
perl -lne 'print $1 if /regsvr32.exe (.*?\.dll)/'
```

Can anyone suggest something less ridiculous?

Also, I’d love any explanation of Perl’s -F argument that is more enlightening than perldoc perlrun.

Comment: Not sure if it's any less ridiculous, but here's an alternate (that's probably far from optimal).  `curl -vs https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/971058/how-do-i-reset-windows-update-components 2>&1 | grep -Po 'regsvr32.exe (.*?\.dll)' | cut -d ' ' -f 2`

Comment: You are trying to parse a messy HTML with a simple regex in a one-liner.  Why not a nice little script with, say,  [HTML::TreeBuilder](http://search.cpan.org/~kentnl/HTML-Tree-5.07/lib/HTML/TreeBuilder.pm)? It'll be a breeze. Btw, you didn't really state exactly what you are "_interested in_" -- the "_looks like this_" didn't clear it up for me.

Comment: @zdim Basically a no-fuss, easy solution.  I tried to clarify my question a bit.  I tend to switch to C# or C++ once the problem gets into script territory, just because I'm so much more comfortable with those languages.

Comment: Sure, and given what the goal is (good edit, thank you) that _is_ indeed doable nicely, as in the answer.  But recall that some kinds of jobs, like parsing (X)HTML, are incomparably simpler with a script than with C++ (which I like and use -- not complaining about the language), because of all those excellent modules.

Comment: @zdim - C# has pretty extensive support for this stuff built-in, but I suspect perl or python make it easier.  (and of course don't require an explicit compile step).  Python's already used a little bit where I work (and tends to be present on Windows machines), but perl solves sooo many of my little problems, I'm torn on which one to learn.  So I'm crappy at both :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to split on `<li>` elements or use a parser (you don't care about the structure of the document), so you can just search for the `regsvr32.exe` string up to the next `<` character.

```
curl $msft_url | perl -lane 'print for ( m|regsvr32.exe (.+?.dll)<|g );'
```

To handle more than one capture, you will need an extra `while` loop to iterate over the pairs of matches.  The `shift` command pulls the first element off of an array, the `reverse` command reverses an array.  This captures 2 strings and prints them in reverse order:

```
curl $msft_url | perl -lane '@m = m|(regsvr32).exe (.+?.dll)<|g; while (@m) { print join " ", reverse(shift @m, shift @m) };'
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect.  The disadvantage of not really using perl for scripting is it's harder to learn efficient tricks like this...because of course, I don't really know perl.  So this answer is a gold mine.  I noticed if I added additional capture groups, everything gets printed.  Fantastic.  I don't suppose there's an easy way to structure the output from a loop like this?  For example one could do `print "$2 $1"` with the output from a *single* two capture-group match.

Answer (score 1):

I've discovered how to do the other method I was trying (sort of), which was to have perl do the splitting.  The key is that the `-a` and `-F` do not determine record-splitting behavior.  Only `-0` does.

`-a` splits *each* record (internally) into the @F array, which the documentation now seems *completely* clear on.  The @F array is mostly intended to be used `awk` style so that one can very easily say "print the 2nd column" (`$F[1]`).  So I could rephrase as "`-0` is generally how you get rows and `-a` is generally how you get columns, roughly speaking."

However, it can be made to serve the purpose:

```
curl -vs \
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/971058/how-do-i-reset-windows-update-components 2>&1 \
| perl -F'<\/li>' -lane 'foreach my $match (map { /regsvr32.exe (.+?.dll)/ } @F) {print"$match"}
```

I, for obvious reasons, prefer the accepted solution for this problem, but I could see this approach being handy elsewhere.
PS--A `-0` solution (using records split on `>`) is:

```
| perl -0x3c -ne 'print "$1\n" if /regsvr32.exe (.+?\.dll)/'
```

Comment: @zdim - I went into this incorrectly thinking `-F` was a more powerful way of doing the same thing.  And while `| perl -0x3c -ne 'print "$1\n" if /regsvr32.exe (.+?\.dll)/'` does the trick...ugggh, that feels a little too disrespectful of html even for me.  Somehow splitting on `</li>` seems....somewhat reasonable.

Comment: OK, clear now :)  I cleaned up my comments which were out of place after edit.

Comment: @zdim does the row/column thing make sense too?  If it wasn't making sense to you, I'm not sure it's going to help someone who doesn't understand how `-F` and `-0` behave (like I didn't).  I wonder if a tiny, simple example of what I mean would be helpful...or out of place?

Comment: When you say "column" I think of splitting each line of data into chunks so those lines up into "column"s. Which is what `-F` does so that seemed OK to me.  But a "row" to me means a line of data ... so I don't see how that relates to `-0`, which returns the whole file. Even if you think of that file being broken up by `<` I still don't see "row"s there.  My thinking. An example is always good, I think. (If you wish to get across how you view it in terms of rows and columns -- which isn't necessary here. It's fine already that you showed how to do it with `-F`.)

Comment: @zdim - Well, like for example if you pipe the output of `find -print0` to perl and you're parsing that output, not the files themselves.. `-0` or explicitly `-0x0` properly separate each file/dir into its own perl record (which would've been a row with just `find`).  Might actually be worth one of those dumb posts where you answer your own question.

Comment: OK, I see what you mean -- but it still doesn't make me comfy with "rows"s :)  (But I am splitting hairs here :)